# find file path in os.walk() in Python

Tags: python-3.x, os.walk

```
import os
   for folder, subfolder, file in os.walk ('SomePath'):
     for filename in file:
        if filename.endswith('.nfo'):
           os.unlink(path)
```

How could i find absolute path of file and pass it to os.unlink(path) ???
.nfo file can be anywhere like SomePath/folder/subfolder/file ?

os.unlink(os.path.abspath(filename)) will not help.
If i try glob.glob, it will just search the current dir(folder at SomePath).

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
for folder, subfolder, file in os.walk('SomePath'):
 for filename in file:
    if filename.endswith('.srt'):
        os.unlink(os.path.join(folder,filename))
```

looks like above worked. if now i replace last line with print(filename), i don't get list of .srt files

Answer (score 0):

To get all files of a directory, and / or subdirectories, I re-use the following code in many of my projects:

```
import os
def get_all_files(rootdir, mindepth = 1, maxdepth = float('inf')):
    """
    Usage:

    d = get_all_files(rootdir, mindepth = 1, maxdepth = 2)

    This returns a list of all files of a directory, including all files in
    subdirectories. Full paths are returned.

    WARNING: this may create a very large list if many files exists in the 
    directory and subdirectories. Make sure you set the maxdepth appropriately.

    rootdir  = existing directory to start
    mindepth = int: the level to start, 1 is start at root dir, 2 is start 
               at the sub direcories of the root dir, and-so-on-so-forth.
    maxdepth = int: the level which to report to. Example, if you only want 
               in the files of the sub directories of the root dir, 
               set mindepth = 2 and maxdepth = 2. If you only want the files
               of the root dir itself, set mindepth = 1 and maxdepth = 1
    """
    rootdir = os.path.normcase(rootdir)
    file_paths = []
    root_depth = rootdir.rstrip(os.path.sep).count(os.path.sep) - 1
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        depth = dirpath.count(os.path.sep) - root_depth
        if mindepth <= depth <= maxdepth:
            for filename in files:
                file_paths.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
        elif depth > maxdepth:
            del dirs[:]  
    return file_paths
```

After that, you can filter, slice and dice anyway you want. If you want to filter inside this routine the place to do it is after `for filename in files:` and before `file_paths.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))`

HTH.